# Thread waiting (vs) new instance

Tags: java, android, performance

I'm trying to optimize my android app, it's a big app and it's taking a lot of battery while running. So I'm trying to see what I can do to fix that.

I ran DDMS and looked at the threads, there are a lot : almost 30. The ones I create through instances of AsyncTask are in "Wait" state. In my code I create them, run some code in "doInBackground" and never touch them again.
From what I understand so far, it means they are done working for now, and something called "Object.wait()" on them.
So first : What is this something, how does it works ?
And : Every time I want my code to run in a new Thread, I create a new AsyncTask instance. Does this "something" wake the old thread, or should I keep a trace of the thread, destroy it when I'm done ?

Thanks for helping me understand.

Answer (score 0):

The page

http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html

tells that "To use it, you must subclass AsyncTask and implement the doInBackground() callback method, which runs in a pool of background threads. "

So as a matter of fact AsyncTasks will reuse the old threads.